# Allocating quantities to different buckets using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, distribution, buckets

I am trying to put together some SQL code that is able to distribute a certain quantity among buckets with a limited capacity for this quantity in a specific order but in separate transactions. See below for example.

I have 2 buckets, each with a certain capacity (integer):

```
bucket       capacity
1            100
2            50
```

I have certain quantities to be bucketed in a number of transactions:

```
transaction   quantity
1             50
2             60
3             20
4             40
```

I want the following result after running the SQL code, which should keep the transaction number and tell me how much each bucket was able to hold of that quantity. The buckets have to be filled in order of the bucket number, and in order of transaction number:

```
transaction   quantity_bucketed   bucket_id   overage
1             50                  1           0
2             50                  1           0
2             10                  2           0
3             20                  2           0
4             20                  2           20
```

If there are no more buckets, and there is still a quantity to be bucketed, it should go to the "overage" column as in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS buckets;
CREATE TABLE buckets (
    bucket_id bigserial primary key,
    capacity integer);

-- something to put in the buckets
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transactions;
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    transaction_id bigserial primary key,
    quantity integer);

-- create 2 buckets with different capacities
INSERT INTO buckets (capacity)
VALUES (100),(50);

-- create some traffic to put in the buckets
INSERT INTO transactions (quantity)
VALUES (50),(60),(20),(40);


WITH buckets AS (
    -- expand buckets (create a row per bucket capacity)
    SELECT row_number() OVER () bucket_row_id, *
    FROM (
        -- slot = a unit of capacity
        SELECT *, generate_series(1,b.capacity) slot 
        FROM buckets b
    ) useless_alias
), xact AS (
    -- expand transactions, creating an id per unit of quantity
    SELECT row_number() OVER () unit_row_id, *
    FROM (
        -- an item per transaction quantity
        SELECT *, generate_series(1,t.quantity) unit 
        FROM transactions t
    ) useless_alias
), filled AS (
    -- join buckets to transactions on slots=units
    --   slots with no units = wasted bucket capacity
    --   units with no slots = overage
    SELECT b.*, x.*
    FROM xact x
    FULL JOIN buckets b
    ON b.bucket_row_id = x.unit_row_id
)
-- finally, do the do
SELECT transaction_id, CASE WHEN bucket_id IS NULL THEN 'overage' ELSE bucket_id::text END bucket_id , count(unit_row_id) quantity_bucketed
FROM filled
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Caveat:  I didn't try to make an extra column out of the "overage".  When filling buckets, it's kinda irrelevant which bucket the overage *didn't* fit into.  In the example case, only 1 transaction had overage.  I'm assuming in your real use case that if there were more transactions, you'd really like to see quantities per transaction not bucketed.

Comment: Can you explain a little what each part of the SQL is doing? Namely `with`, `over`, `xact`, `slot`, `unit`, and `generate_series`.

Comment: So I got this working for my application, however it gets very very slow for any "large" quantities (e.g. it will have to create millions of rows for a large amount.) Is there any way you can think of off the bat to optimize this query?

Comment: @veggie1 ...only if the overage or wasted capacity is very lopsided and you can remove a lot of rows by doing a LEFT or RIGHT join, and then just counting the leftover rows.   I am not going to modify the example for this, because it would just make it very hard to read in order to solve a corner case.

Answer (score 0):

--I have edited the answer provided above by @kirk-roybal to fit within SQL 2017 syntax.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Numbers;

DECLARE @UpperBound INT = 1000000;

;WITH cteN(Number) AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) - 1
  FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS s2
)
SELECT [Number] INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM cteN WHERE [Number] <= @UpperBound;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_dboNumber ON dbo.Numbers([Number])


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #buckets;
CREATE TABLE #buckets (
    bucket_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    capacity integer);

-- something to put in the buckets
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #transactions;
CREATE TABLE #transactions (
    transaction_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    quantity integer);

-- create 2 buckets with different capacities
INSERT INTO #buckets (capacity)
VALUES (100),(50);

-- create some traffic to put in the buckets
INSERT INTO #transactions (quantity)
VALUES (50),(60),(20),(40);

select * from #buckets
select * from #transactions;


WITH buckets AS (
    -- expand buckets (create a row per bucket capacity)
    SELECT bucket_row_id = row_number() OVER (Order By bucket_id) , *
    FROM (
        -- slot = a unit of capacity
        SELECT b.*, N.Number slot 
        FROM #buckets b
        CROSS JOIN dbo.Numbers N
        WHERE N.Number >0 AND N.Number <= b.capacity
    ) useless_alias
), xact AS (
    -- expand transactions, creating an id per unit of quantity
    SELECT unit_row_id = row_number() OVER (Order by transaction_id) , *
    FROM (
        -- an item per transaction quantity
        SELECT t.*, N.Number unit 
        FROM #transactions t
        CROSS JOIN dbo.Numbers N 
        WHERE N.Number > 0 AND N.Number <= t.quantity
    ) useless_alias
), filled AS (
    -- join buckets to transactions on slots=units
    --   slots with no units = wasted bucket capacity
    --   units with no slots = overage
    SELECT b.*, x.*
    FROM xact x
    FULL JOIN buckets b ON b.bucket_row_id = x.unit_row_id
)
-- finally, do the do
SELECT transaction_id
    , bucket_id = CASE WHEN bucket_id IS NULL THEN 'overage' ELSE CAST(bucket_id as varchar(200)) END  
    , count(unit_row_id) quantity_bucketed
FROM filled
GROUP BY transaction_id,  CASE WHEN bucket_id IS NULL THEN 'overage' ELSE CAST(bucket_id as varchar(200)) END 
ORDER BY 1,2
```